# How prevent redirect in flasgger requests?

Tags: python, flasgger

I check below code in cmd - its not redirected to another url.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5555/login" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"admin\", \"password\": \"admin\"}"
```

But when i click in browser `Execute` - its catch redirect and output is incorrect. How disallow redirect for it?

Comment: We can't possibly answer that without seeing the Python and HTML code.  There are many things you could have done wrong.

Comment: @TimRoberts i simply want disable redirect in swagger.